# Posting a comment on a page through native iOS UI

Tags: ios, comments, facebook-comments

Ok so I've scoured the docs and stackoverflow for an answer, but maybe I'm asking the wrong questions or looking in the wrong places. I'm working on an native iOS app and I want to give the user a way to post a comment to a page, but through native UI and not through a UIWebView with the comments plugin embedded. I can make a comment on a comment on the page, but I can't seem to make a comment from an authenticated user on the page itself. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) provides you with the ability to set credentials for basic HTTP authentication, but it sounds like you're talking about logging in to some kind of forum system.  The way those generally work is that you send your credentials to the site, and get an authentication cookie back.  You then need to provide that cookie to the system when you interact with the site.

[Here's a blog post with an example](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2011/04/11/Working-with-cookies-and-http-in-objective-c) of how to do that.

Comment: Yeah actually this is in regards to the facebook-comments plugin and the ability to add a comment via the graph api or fpl through native UI.

Comment: In your case, you might be interested in this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/